# How to add append comments to a targeted form when page has multiple identical forms

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I created a page with many posts, where each post has a comment section. I want to be able to submit a comment and have the comment added to the 'ul' element within each post. I tried adding an eventListener with a 'submit' event on elements with the '.comment-section' class, however it doesn't even trigger the console log I have in the callback function, nor is preventDefault doing anything, so I don't think I'm selecting the correct element to access the submitted value. How do I select the element I need and access the submitted value?

edit - I updated the code to include the missing bracket. The link for the array of images, is a site with a text file like so: ["url", "url", "url"]. The images are not a concern here, I am trying to implement the comment section.

```js
function newPost (imgSrc) {
  $('#feed').append('<div class="post"></div>');
  const newPost = $('.post').last();
  newPost.append(`<img class="feed-img" src="${imgSrc}"></img>`);
  newPost.append('<div class="user-block"></div>');
  const userBlock = $('.user-block').last();
  userBlock.after('<ul class="comment-list"></ul>');
  $('.comment-list').last().toggleClass('hidden');
  newPost.append('<form class="comment-form"><input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Add a comment..." class="comment-section"></input><input type="submit" value="Post" class="submit-comment"></input></form>');
}
  
$.get('imagearray.net/images', function(data, status){
  const imgArray = data;
  imgArray.forEach((pic) =>{
     newPost(pic);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>I need HTML here to support and reproduce the issue at hand please</div>
```

Comment: the code you shared throws an exception because the function `newPost` has no closing `}` ... after correcting that and when invoked, it correctly adds the elements to the parent #feed

Comment: since you didn't share any other detail but a function and the whole form submission is quite unclear in your question, it would be helpful to know where that imgsrc is expected to come from because otherwise the logic was going to work even just doing something like `<button onclick="addPost();">Add</button>`

Comment: Please add the smallest possible set of HTML that reproduces this issue - I edited the snippet to assist you in where to add it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the HTML right on the page, then clone it and change the img src and then append it - makes maintaining the HTML easier than the string IMHO.

All you need is to trap the button click (I change it to actually BE a button of type "button".  Then find the form it is on and submit it.
This is probably NOT the way to do this since the submit will refresh the screen etc. See other example.

```js
/* this is all you need */
$("#feed").on('click', '.submit-comment', function(event) {
  let postform = $(this).closest('form.comment-form');
  postform.submit();
});

function newPost(imgSrc) {
  const feed = $('#feed');
  let postBlock = $('#fake-block').find(".post").clone(true);
  postBlock.find('.feed-img').attr("src", imgSrc);
  postBlock.appendTo(feed);
}
$.get('imagearray.net/images', function(data, status) {
    const imgArray = data;
    imgArray.forEach((pic) => {
      newPost(pic);
    });
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
  }).always(function() {
    // alert("complete");
  });
```

```css
.fake-block {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="feed" class="help-me-container"></div>
</div>
<div id="fake-block" class="fake-block">
  <div class="post">
    <img class="feed-img" src="none" alt="fake missing" />
    <div class="user-block"></div>
    <ul class="comment-list"></ul>
    <form class="comment-form">
      <div class="input-container">
        <input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Add a comment..." class="comment-section" /><button type="button" class="submit-comment">Post</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now what your probably can just post the data to a URL on the server, then update the screen - commented out the ajax part which posts it.
I created some fake data/pictures which is not part of this question really but just gives us something to "submit" to the page.

Somewhat elaborate since we fake the post (which likely returns JSON or some such.

```js
var postThingy = {
  wefake: true,
  newPost: function(imgSrc) {
    const feed = $('#feed');
    let postBlock = $('#fake-block').find(".post").clone(true);
    postBlock.find('.feed-img').attr("src", imgSrc);
    postBlock.appendTo(feed);
  },
  init: function(fake) {
    postThingy.wefake = fake;
    // all you really need, change "real-submit" to "click"
    $("#feed").on('post-data', '.submit-comment', function(event, postdata) {
      /* fake it for now */
      $(this).trigger('update-screen', [postdata]);
      /*
      $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "serverpostcommenturlhere",
          data: postdata,
          buttonholder:{ button:this, updates:postdata }
        })
        .done(function(msg) {
          alert("Comment Saved: " + msg);
           $(this.buttonholder.button).trigger('update-screen'[this.buttonholder.updates);
        });
        */
    });
    // update the screen
    $("#feed").on('update-screen', '.submit-comment', function(event, updates) {
      let postform = $(this).closest('form.comment-form');
      let textVal = updates.comment;
      let newComment = $("<li class='comment-item'></li>").text(textVal);
      postform.prev('.comment-list').append(newComment);
    });
    // just an elaborate way to demo here. We could do whatever we want before we trigger
    $("#feed").on('click', '.submit-comment', function(event) {
      let postform = $(this).closest('form.comment-form');
      let formText = postform.find('input[type="text"].comment-section').val();
      // some user context assumed here
      let user = "Freddy Friendly";
      let postdata = {
        "comment": formText,
        "user": user
      };
      $(this).trigger('post-data', [postdata]);
    });
    // just an elaborate way to put some images up
    if (postThingy.wefake) {
      let fakeImages = ["https://picsum.photos/200/300", "https://picsum.photos/200", "https://picsum.photos/105", "https://picsum.photos/100"];
      fakeImages.forEach(imageurl => postThingy.newPost(imageurl));
      return;
    } else {
      $.get('imagearray.net/images', function(data, status) {
          const imgArray = data;
          imgArray.forEach((pic) => {
            postThingy.newPost(pic);
          });
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
          alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        })
        .always(function() {
          // alert("complete");
        });
    }
  }
};
//setup the fake the ajax call
postThingy.init(true);
```

```css
.fake-block {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="feed" class="help-me-container"></div>
</div>
<div id="fake-block" class="fake-block">
  <div class="post">
    <img class="feed-img" src="none" alt="fake missing" />
    <div class="user-block"></div>
    <ul class="comment-list"></ul>
    <form class="comment-form">
      <div class="input-container">
        <input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Add a comment..." class="comment-section" /><button type="button" class="submit-comment">Post</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```